# Outputting incorrect username or password

Tags: php

I need help with this code to output incorrect username or password but it doesn't :(

```
  <?php 



include 'functions.php';
if(loggedin()){
header("Location: index.php");
exit();

}
 if(isset($_POST['login'])){

$username=$_POST['Username']; 
$password=$_POST['Password'];


if(isset($_POST['rememberme'])){
    $rememberme = $_POST['rememberme'];


}

if($username&&$password){
    $login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM php_customer WHERE Username='$username'");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($login)){
        $db_password = $row['Password'];
        if($password == $db_password){
            $loginok= TRUE;
        }
            else{
            $loginok= FALSE;

            }

        if($loginok==TRUE)
        {

            if($rememberme=="on"){
                setcookie('Username',$username, time() + 7200);
            }else if ($rememberme==""){
            $_SESSION['Username'] = $username;}
            header("Location: index.php"); 
            exit();
        }

        echo "Incorrect Username or Password";
    }

}
```

}
?>

I've tried adding it by the `$loginok=false;` but nothing works. I don't want you guys to go psycho on me, this is a 1 line of code kinda thing. Also yes I know you can log in if you store a username as a cookie. Just trying to validate atm.

Comment: Please [sanitize](http://bobby-tables.com/) your database queries with [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: with your code you could do an sql injection with a common password and it will get all your users from the table and if it matches any user with that password log you in. nice! You should only return 1 row using `LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 0):

Set your flag to false at the very beginning, before doing the SQL query:

```
 $loginok = FALSE;
 $login = mysql_query(....);
```

Why?  Because the SQL query won't return anything for a username that doesn't exist in the table, obviously.

Which means, also, you need to make sure that the line `echo "Incorrect Username or Password";` and the if-statement based on $loginok are not inside the loop which goes through the recordset, but after it. *Which means you need to learn how to properly indent code so its clear where if-statements and loops begin and end.*